# Javascript Hidden div doesn't want to display on form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a div that is hidden by inline styling on a form. I would like to have the div display when a user checks the "Other" checkbox. Would someone look at my code? It does not work. I think it might be do to my markup, but if it is the javascript code, let me know. Thank you for any help.

html:

```
<div class="item">
   <label>How did you hear about us? <span class="req">*</span></label>
   <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Newspaper" id="CAT_Custom_510976_0" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Newspaper<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Direct Mail" id="CAT_Custom_510976_1" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Direct Mail<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Radio" id="CAT_Custom_510976_2" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Radio<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Billboard" id="CAT_Custom_510976_3" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Billboard<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Online Search" id="CAT_Custom_510976_4" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Online Search<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Friend" id="CAT_Custom_510976_5" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Friend<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Social Media" id="CAT_Custom_510976_6" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Social Media<br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="Other..." id="CAT_Custom_510976_7" name="CAT_Custom_510976" />
   Other...
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="other" class="item">
   <label for="CAT_Custom_510977">Other:</label>
   <br />
   <textarea onKeyDown="if(this.value.length&gt;=4000)this.value=this.value.substring(0,3999);" class="cat_listbox" rows="4" cols="10" id="CAT_Custom_510977" name="CAT_Custom_510977"></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Hide or show textarea if the other checkbox field is checked
        var voucher = document.getElementById("CAT_Custom_510976_7");
        function ShowCCFields(val) {                            
            if (!document.getElementById('other'))
                return;         
            if (voucher.checked == true)
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'inline';
            else{
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually call the function you created. To make your function run when the checkbox is clicked you should change your javascript to:

```
    var voucher = document.getElementById("CAT_Custom_510976_7");
    voucher.addEventListener('click', ShowCCFields);
    function ShowCCFields(val) {                            
        if (!document.getElementById('other'))
            return;         
        if (voucher.checked == true)
            document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'inline';
        else{
            document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

The line `addEventListener` is what then allows the function to run when you the voucher is clicked.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help & clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually assign the function to be called.

```
voucher.onchange = ShowCCFields;
```

Also, remove the `val` that's in the parentheses, since you don't appear to be using it.

Comment: Shouldn't use `change` as some browsers (IE) don't fire `change` event until the checkbox loses focus. Also those browsers will return the _wrong value_ if the `<label>` is clicked (because the label click causes the loss of focus first).